# shiny with problem of unknown function "active"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am setting up a shiny web portal using an external package (https://github.com/liziyie/scDVA).This is an R shiny based tool. However, when I load my own data, it cames with the error below and the web page is frozen with nothing pop out. The error looks like this:

```
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3065
Warning: Error in active: could not find function "active"

  48: shinyjs::toggle
  47: ::
  shiny
  observe
  46: <observer>
   3: runApp
   2: print.shiny.appobj
   1: <Anonymous>
```

My code is here :

```
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body, use_bs_popover())

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Close the server----
  observeEvent(input$close, {
    js$closeWindow()
    stopApp()
  })
  
  # # Loggin Page----
  credentials <- callModule(
    shinyauthr::loginServer,
    "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )
  
  logout_init <-
    callModule(shinyauthr::logoutServer,
               "logout",
               reactive(credentials()$user_auth))
  
  output$Login_logged <- reactive({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'Login_logged', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  # Load data tree-----
  output$LoadDataTree <- renderTree({
    dataset_tree
  })
  
  # Interactive load button----
  observeEvent(input$LoadButton, {
    req(input$LoadDataTree)
    LoadData_selected <- get_selected(input$LoadDataTree, format = "classid") # Record the dataset to load
    LoadData_selected <- LoadData_selected[LoadData_selected %in% dataset_map$DatasetName]
    if (is.null(LoadData_selected)) {
      LoadData_selected <- character(0)
    }
    LoadData.status <-
      loadDataSet(LoadData_selected) # Load the dataset
    showshinyalert(session, "LoadDataset_alert", "Done.",
                   styleclass = "info")
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      inputId = "SelectData_dataset",
      choices = LoadData_selected,
      selected = LoadData_selected[1]
    )
  })
```

Is there anyone know what's the problem ? And how to fix it ?
I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see your _complete_ code, inclusing `library` calls and possibly more.

Comment: It seems the github repo only contains the shiny app, and not the code for the scRNA seq itself. how are you creating the expression profiles for your own dataset? https://github.com/liziyie/scDVA/blob/master/www/User%20Manual%20of%20scDVA.pdf under load own data its explained you also need to update some metadata in ` dataset_map.csv`